# plz help for aws ec2 react+node build error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2, build

I worked react webapp in two different folders 'client'(frontend) and 'server'(backend)
on ec2 sever i cloned my project from git and start npm install in client folder.
then enter npm run build.
and finally i faced with error below.
i have no idea what is wrong with this error...

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (/home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
/home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at module.exports (/home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at /home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at /home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at /home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /home/ec2-user/seezzle/client/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem in ionic react project !

Comment: see the answers below :) it was a matter of Node -version in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Verify your Node version, is a LTS version 14.x.x

```
node --version
```

try to uninstall the current and install LTS https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: thx!! it was a version problem!

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it downgrading my node version to LTS. I was facing this issue in node.17X. When I downgraded to **16.12.0 LTS** my problem is solved.